# How do I make a horizontal user login block for the top user region?

Tags: theming, users

I'm not sure why but Drupal doesn't provide for a horizontal user login with the register or forgot password links. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried editing the style in your theme css?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please select it as the official answer by clicking on the check next to the vote up/down widget.

Comment: I would like to give other people an opportunity to offer different answers.

Comment: Even if you select an answer as the official one, people can still add new answers. The answer has five votes from the community so other people have founded useful too.

Comment: An explanation to why you unaccepted the answer would be great.

Comment: Since none of the answers work for what I need I unchecked it.

Comment: What method did you end up using?

Comment: You didn't end up using css on your theme, I find that hard to believe.

Comment: He is the one that choose his prefered one, not you ipwa.

Answer (score 7):

There are many many ways to do this, there is even a screencast and a module to do this. I would personally do this from the theme layer using css, or if I was using Fusion as a base theme, I would do this from the block configuration (thanks Skinr!)

I'm adding some links that will help you out.

http://drupal.org/project/userloginbar

http://ericlondon.com/changing-user-login-block-horizontal-layout

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMyOX6v-k3Y

http://www.victheme.com/blog/drupal-7-creating-horizontal-login-bar-without-module